# Error handling with invalid MAC entry with Perl Net::MAC module

Tags: perl, error-handling, scripting

I'm attempting write a Perl script that asks the user to enter a MAC address.  I'm using the Net::MAC module to convert whatever format MAC address the user enters to a standard format for me to use later in the script.  I've got most of it working but I can't seem to figure out how to handle a situation in which they enter an invalid MAC.  Something that couldn't possibly be a MAC address.  Such as an entry that includes letters that aren't A-F.

I'm thinking something like the following should work but when it dies it just flat out kills the entire script rather than re-asks the user to enter the MAC again.

```
    use Net::MAC;

    my $proceed = "no";
    while ($proceed eq "no"){
        print "Enter the MAC address: ";
        my $mac;
        $mac = <>;
        chomp($mac);
        my $tempMac = Net::MAC->new('mac' => $mac, 'die' => 0);
        if ($tempMac->die() eq "0"){
            print "Looks like you entered an invalid MAC address.  Please try again.\n";
        } else {
            my $newMac = $tempMac->convert('base' => 16,'bit_group' => 8,'delimeter' => ":");
            $proceed = "yes";
        }
    }
```

Should this instead use something like a Try, Catch statement?  I think in other words, I need to know how to appropriately handle the die() event without having the script completely bail on me.

Comment: According to its documentation, Net::Mac objects don't have a `die` method... What exactly happens with an invalid address? Any error messages etc.?

Comment: I get something like the following if I enter bogus stuff like; 39568jkl:
"discovery of MAC address metadata failed, invalid characters in MAC address "00:00:39:56:8j:kl" at ./RTTest.pl line 124"

I want to be able to test on that and loop back around and ask the user to re-enter the MAC address again.

Comment: I need to sit down and actually play with the code, but error handling in this module is really strange. When die is 0, it just stores an error message and keeps on trying to do its thing, causing more errors. It'll print the error using carp if die is 0 and verbose is 1, but it shouldn't croak if die is 0.

Comment: Looks like you should be using `$tempMac->get_error()` and seeing if it returns `undef` or not for checking to see if there was an error. I wonder if `tempMac->die()` is calling the built in `die`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://mvp.kablamo.org/essentials/die-eval for some info on how exceptions work in Perl and how to handle them. Consider [Syntax::Keyword::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Keyword::Try) for a familiar try/catch paradigm.

```
use Syntax::Keyword::Try;
my $newMac;
try {
    my $tempMac = Net::MAC->new('mac' => $mac);
    $newMac = $tempMac->convert('base' => 16,'bit_group' => 8,'delimeter' => ":");
    $proceed = "yes";
} catch {
    print "Looks like you entered an invalid MAC address. Error: $@ Please try again.\n";
}
```

You can also validate the mac address before passing it to Net::MAC using something like [Regexp::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::net#$RE%7Bnet%7D%7BMAC%7D).

```
use Regexp::Common 'net';
my $newMac;
if ($mac =~ m/$RE{net}{MAC}/) {
    my $tempMac = Net::MAC->new('mac' => $mac);
    $newMac = $tempMac->convert('base' => 16,'bit_group' => 8,'delimeter' => ":");
    $proceed = "yes";
} else {
    print "Looks like you entered an invalid MAC address. Please try again.\n";
}
```